# Passing char as argument

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int sk03(char * a)   //DELETE! DELEEEEETE!
{                      //(Or "Exterminate! EXTERMINAAAAAATE!" if that's your thing.)
    int b = sk00(a);
    int c = 0;
    while(a[b] != '!')
    {
        a[c] = a[b];
        c++;b++;
    }
    cout << a << "\n";
    int your_mom = 0;
    return your_mom;
}

int main()
{
    char * str = "``sk`sk!";
    return sk03(str);
}
```

This method works fine for when you want to pass the entire string to the function, but how would one pass just the second half of the string to sk03? Would I have to create a complete new array?

Comment: where is the definition for sk00()?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is going wrong?

Comment: pass starting from position you want. (i.e. `sk03(str + n)`), where `n` is index from starting character of your "second half".

Comment: I didn't include sk00. It just finds the length.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just pass a pointer to the element you want:

```
char a[100];
sk03( a + 50 );     // call function passing second half of the array
```

Comment: Oh, wait, not if I define it as char a = "``sk`sk!"

Comment: @Robert Lennon: yes because you need to intialize "a" first with some characters..

Answer (score 1):

Pass it like

```
char * str = "``sk`sk!";
return sk03(&str[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

for example you can modify your code to do something like this:

```
char  str[STRING_LENGTH] = "``sk`sk!";
return sk03(&str[3]);
```